# Ruby: Use XPath, and get string index of matches?

Tags: ruby, xpath

Is it possible to get the string indices of all the matches returned by doing an XPath search?

For example if I do this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(htmlSource)

doc.xpath('//meta[case_insensitive_equals(@name,"author")]', XpathFunctions.new)
```

It gives me all the elements that matches. But how can I get the string index for each match? In other words, the index of the entire HTML source the element begins in?

Example Inputs:

```
<HTML><meta name="author" content="test"></HTML>
```

Example Output:
I want the index 6, since that's where the meta tag starts

Comment: Could you please provide an example of input and the desired output?

Comment: I added it Carlo Cannas

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear. But, why do you need such thing? I don't know Ruby's libraries, but usually once a document is parsed, there's no more a reference to the various tokens in the input string.

Answer (score 1):

String index? No. Line index? Yes, but, there's a caveat: XML and HTML are NOT line based formats. A line number doesn't have a lot of meaning to them, so, while you can get a line-number, you might find a document only has one line, and you're no better off knowing the number.

Here's a quick test using http://www.example.com to get the line number of the first `<p>` tag:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.example.com/'))
first_p = doc.at('p')
first_p.line # => 45
first_p.to_html 
# => "<p>This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this\n    domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>"
```

Once you know what line the tag is on you *could* mess with it by searching through that line in the document.

But, why? If you want to modify the line, it's easily done using Nokogiri's [`replace`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-replace) method. If you want to extract just that portion of the line, it's easily done using [`to_html`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-to_html).